# redux state is changing but component is not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have problem with re-rendering component. Store is updating allright, but the component is no refreshing - don't know why. I

Here is reducer

```
const initialState = {
    actualCurrencies: [
        {
            id: "GBP",
            sell: null,
            buy: null
        }
    ]
}


        case "updateCurrencies":
        console.log(action.data);
            return {...state,
                actualCurrencies: [
                    {
                        id: "GBP",
                        sell: action.data[0].sell,
                        buy: action.data[0].buy
                    }
                ]
            }
```

What is wrong with that? I guess that is problem with mutable but why? I'm using spred operation sow it suppose to work.

Comment: @MatanBobi That's incorrect...the above code is meant to ensure that the other keys remain constant while the `actualCurrencies` key gets overriden by the data given above. This code is just fine. Your issue is probably with your component. Try checking if the state changes in your `mapStateToProps` function.

Comment: @ManavM You're right, totally missed the question's purpose. Sorry my bad.

Comment: any ideas? ...

here is link to github with all project:

https://github.com/bsmolin/Gielda

Answer (score 0):

That's my connect component with store

```
    export default connect(state => 
    ({
        currencies: state.auth.currencies,
        money: state.auth.money
    }),
    { updateCurrencies }
)(BodyLogIn);
```

I used that in another component, but without array and it's working. Do i need to have some code into render that react know that something changed?